# gem5 X86 full system mode run fails with: "Can't find file 'x86root.img' on path"

Tags: gem5

I am new to gem5. I downloaded and compiled gem5 successfully. However when I try to run the system in X86 Full Simulation mode I get the following error:

IOError:

> Can't find file 'x86root.img' on path.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't provide a specific disk image e.g. with `fs.py --disk-image` gem5 searches for one with a default name under the `M5_PATH` environment variable.

A full working CLI should look something like:

```
M5_PATH=opt/system \
  ./build/X86/gem5.opt \
  configs/example/fs.py \
  --disk-image rootfs.ext2 \
  --kernel vmlinux \
  --mem-size 256MB \
  --num-cpus 1 \
  --command-line 'earlyprintk=ttyS0 lpj=7999923 root=/dev/sda console_msg_format=syslog nokaslr norandmaps panic=-1 printk.devkmsg=on printk.time=y rw console=ttyS0' \
;
```

To help you get started, also consider this [highly automated setup that just works](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/7ec28d680854adb8b425abf8bd8d055144055112#gem5-buildroot-setup-getting-started).

In future questions, please provide the full gem5 CLI you've tried, and the exact gem5 git SHA version.

See also: [Gem 5 IOError: Can't find a path to system files. Full System X86 simulation setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56319473/gem-5-ioerror-cant-find-a-path-to-system-files-full-system-x86-simulation-set/56320982#56320982)