# Gem 5 IOError: Can't find a path to system files. Full System X86 simulation setup

Tags: gem5

I've already got Gem5 installed. 
I'm trying to do a full system simulation. 
I added M5_PATH

```
echo "export M5_PATH==/home/sam/security/gem5/full/" >> ~/.bashrc
```

I put all the system image and config files under following directory:

```
  :~/security/gem5/full$ ls
binaries  configs  config-x86.tar.bz2  disks  x86-system.tar.bz2  x86-system.tar.bz2.1
```

I changed the path in the SysPaths.py file to following:

```
                paths = [ '/dist/m5/system', 'full' ]
```

And updated the following line in  Benchmark.py

```
            return env.get('LINUX_IMAGE', disk('linux-x86.img'))
```

Gem5 is compiled successfully and I'm running the following:

```
 ./build/X86/gem5.opt configs/example/fs.py  --disk-image=/home/sam/security/gem5/full/disks/linux-x86.img
```

But I get an error that it can't find a path to system files.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/X86/python/m5/main.py", line 438, in main
    exec(filecode, scope)
  File "configs/example/fs.py", line 335, in <module>
    test_sys = build_test_system(np)
  File "configs/example/fs.py", line 93, in build_test_system
    cmdline=cmdline)
  File "/home/sam/security/gem5/configs/common/FSConfig.py", line 614, in makeLinuxX86System
    makeX86System(mem_mode, numCPUs, mdesc, self, Ruby)
  File "/home/sam/security/gem5/configs/common/FSConfig.py", line 539, in makeX86System
    disk0.childImage(mdesc.disk())
  File "/home/sam/security/gem5/configs/common/Benchmarks.py", line 59, in disk
    return disk(self.diskname)
  File "/home/sam/security/gem5/configs/common/SysPaths.py", line 63, in __call__
    raise IOError("Can't find a path to system files.")
IOError: Can't find a path to system files.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update 2020-01**

As of 82f6d6e90f36e400db1f38eef5fe17430313458e reviewed at https://gem5-review.googlesource.com/c/public/gem5/+/23672/7 the CLI insanity has reduced substantially:

- `M5_PATH` is not required anymore on X86 if you point to all required files explicitly:

  ```
  fs.py --kernel path/to/vmlinux --disk-image path/to/rootfs.ext2
  ```

  The second disk named `linux-bigswap2.img` and `x86_64-vmlinux-2.6.22.9` are not needed anymore, and you can pass multiple disks at will with multiple `--disk-image` options, see: [How to attach multiple disk images in a simulation with gem5 fs.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50862906/how-to-attach-multiple-disk-images-in-a-simulation-with-gem5-fs-py/60210181#60210181)
- on ARM, `M5_PATH` can also be dispensed, but you also need to point the bootloader with:

  ```
  fs.py --bootloader ./system/arm/bootloader/arm64/boot.arm64
  ```

If you miss any of those files, `M5_PATH` gets used.

Note that just like the `PATH` search algorithm, paths without `/` are only searched under `M5_PATH`, so if you want to point to a file in the current directory you need to add `./` as in:

```
fs.py --kernel ./vmlinux
```

see also: [Why do you need ./ (dot-slash) before executable or script name to run it in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331075/why-do-you-need-dot-slash-before-executable-or-script-name-to-run-it-in-bas/58626235#58626235)

**Old answer**

gem5 is picky about some path names, but you don't need to patch it to achieve a decent image setup.

For example, [this working setup](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/3527c8df5bf278edd3c387e916ebe4499247f364#gem5-buildroot-setup-getting-started) with gem5 e2656006df442a995bf80ee03fa9700d6ec14537 essentially runs:

```
M5_PATH=/full/path/to/system \
  build/X86/gem5.opt \
  configs/example/fs.py \
  --disk-image /any/path/to/rootfs.ext2 \
  --kernel /any/path/to/vmlinux
```

and `/full/path/to/system` contains:

```
./disks/linux-bigswap2.img
./binaries/x86_64-vmlinux-2.6.22.9
```

Both of those files are dummies which I generated [from here](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/3527c8df5bf278edd3c387e916ebe4499247f364/build-gem5) with:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=./binaries/linux-bigswap2.img count=1 bs=16k
touch disks/x86_64-vmlinux-2.6.22.9
```

Yes, this is a horrible workaround to gem5's opinionated image searching... someone should really patch gem5 to not look for those images if you pass `--disk-image` and `--kernel` yourself...

As always, have a try at debugging it with prints and PDB: it should then be simple to figure out why something didn't work for you.

Comment: Thank you Ciro! It solved the problem. :) My simulation is running now and hasn't thrown any error so far. What does `dd if=/dev/zero of=./binaries/linux-bigswap2.img count=1 bs=16k` do exactly?

Comment: @parisa great! It creates a 16KiB file full of zeroes, some minimal size appears to be required for gem5 not to complain. Have a look at `man dd`, google `/dev/zero` and play with `hd binaries/linux-bigswap2.img` ;-)