# GEM5 Full System Simulation for X86 Fatal Error: No kernel to load

Tags: linux, gem5

I need to run FS mode `Gem5` for `X86` architecture. Following all the available instructions:

1. I set the environment variable using:

```
M5_PATH="/home/vikas/full_system_images/" >> ./.bashrc
```

2. When I try to run the Gem5 as following:

```
./build/X86/gem5.opt configs/example/fs.py --disk-image=/home/mysys/full-system-images/disks/linux-x86.img
```

I get the error:

```
warn: CheckedInt already exists in allParams. This may be caused by the Python 2.7 compatibility layer.
warn: Enum already exists in allParams. This may be caused by the Python 2.7 compatibility layer.
warn: ScopedEnum already exists in allParams. This may be caused by the Python 2.7 compatibility layer.
gem5 Simulator System.  http://gem5.org
gem5 is copyrighted software; use the --copyright option for details.

gem5 version 20.0.0.2
gem5 compiled Jun 22 2020 16:34:19
gem5 started Jun 23 2020 16:08:24
gem5 executing on pc80-99-linux, pid 3941
command line: ./build/X86/gem5.opt configs/example/fs.py --disk-image=/home/mysys/full-system-images/disks/linux-x86.img

Global frequency set at 1000000000000 ticks per second
warn: No dot file generated. Please install pydot to generate the dot file and pdf.
warn: DRAM device capacity (8192 Mbytes) does not match the address range assigned (512 Mbytes)
info: No kernel set for full system simulation. Assuming you know what you're doing.
system.pc.com_1.device: Listening for connections on port 3456
      0: system.pc.south_bridge.cmos.rtc: Real-time clock set to Sun Jan  1 00:00:00 2012
0: system.remote_gdb: listening for remote gdb on port 7000
warn: Reading current count from inactive timer.
***fatal: fatal condition !kernelObj occurred: No kernel to load.***
Memory Usage: 674344 KBytes
```

I really need help to find out how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

`M5_PATH` is not needed anymore as shown at: [Gem 5 IOError: Can't find a path to system files. Full System X86 simulation setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56319473/gem-5-ioerror-cant-find-a-path-to-system-files-full-system-x86-simulation-set/56320982#56320982) just point to your kernel image explicitly with `--kernel` which is much less likely to go wrong.

If it still doesn't work, try debugging a but further, or diff out with [this fully automated setup that just works](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/da40e840751a08d56a69000d937834d126b4660e#gem5-buildroot-setup-getting-started).

Mailing list thread: https://www.mail-archive.com/gem5-users@gem5.org/msg17940.html